# Tool to analyze the executable

Tags: c#, java, c++, compiler-construction, pascal

is there a tool that analyzes the executable and detects:
    - the programming language used (compiler),
    - frameworks used (Qt, Gtk, .Net, WxWidgets etc),
    - other useful information (compression, etc.).

I know it is quite hard to tell the programming language sometimes (especially in C or Pascal exes), but it is possible to tell the language or compiler used? (Delphi generates exes differently, VB6 too for instance).

It may be possible eg. with dependency analysis of the dlls, headers etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try checking the Magic Numbers to give you a start point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files

Comment: @KingCronus the magic number for executables on Windows is almost always [`PE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Comment: @CodeCaster that's interesting I didn't realise that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used in the past (uni) [PEInfo](http://www.pazera-software.com/products/peinfo/), but it did not give information you want. After that I used reflector as I knew my dll/exe where .net

But **I think there is no software to do that**.

**Workaround:** Best thing you can do is look in the strings of exe (for example use Process explorer) and guess yourself.

Answer (score 4):

On GNU, you can use several tools to try to guess the informartion you want :

- ldd to resolv shared libraries linked to the binary
- nm to list symbols Imported/exporeted by the binary
- strings, which can dump the strings embedded in the binary
- objdump can be useful too
- A hex editor can be useful too.

I guess there are similar tools on the windows plateform. Dumpbin.exe is something similar to nm, and depends.exe to ldd iirc.

Btw, java is often bytecode compiled, not native.

Answer (score 1):

Open your executable in a binary file viewer and look for strings that look like names of the functions. These strings are not always available, but in certain cases they are present. They can be used to resolve links with DLLs for example. After that google those strings. There is a chance that they will tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a possible way to do this correctly. Maybe some basic programming languages can be detected but nobody can detect frameworks used. There are thousands of frameworks.